# Fuchsia OS : Installation on ubuntu using qemu

Tags: fuchsia

I am trying to install Fuchsia on my UBUNTU 16.04 system.

When I am trying to do run `fbuild` command I am getting following logs.

It is throwing error:

```
*
[00000.000] 00000.00000> multiboot: info @ 0xffffff8000009500 flags 0x24f
[00000.000] 00000.00000> multiboot: cmdline @ 0xffffff8000266041
[00000.000] 00000.00000> multiboot: ramdisk @ 00267000..13428590
[00000.000] 00000.00000> bootdata: @ 0xffffff8000267000 (320607632 bytes)
[00000.000] 00000.00000>
[00000.000] 00000.00000> welcome to lk/MP
[00000.000] 00000.00000>
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff8017c82c (global_prng_seed) at level 0x30000, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff8015bae4 (elf_build_id) at level 0x3fffe, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff8015ba50 (version) at level 0x3ffff, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> version:
[00000.000] 00000.00000>        arch:     X86
[00000.000] 00000.00000>        platform: PC
[00000.000] 00000.00000>        target:   PC_X86
[00000.000] 00000.00000>        project:  MAGENTA_PC_X86_64
[00000.000] 00000.00000>        buildid:  GIT_3BAD4F3F4D28407FB56C0AF3537A01333B3E0ACD
[00000.000] 00000.00000>        ELF build ID: d2ee08a28ddd6d36f4be2d6b0a4d23c3493f0ad2
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff8015fa54 (vm_preheap) at level 0x3ffff, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> initializing heap
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff8015fcc8 (vm) at level 0x50000, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> VM: reserving kernel region [ffffffff80100000, ffffffff801b5000) flags 0x28 name 'kernel_code'
[00000.000] 00000.00000> VM: reserving kernel region [ffffffff801b5000, ffffffff801e9000) flags 0x8 name 'kernel_rodata'
[00000.000] 00000.00000> VM: reserving kernel region [ffffffff801e9000, ffffffff801f0000) flags 0x18 name 'kernel_data'
[00000.000] 00000.00000> VM: reserving kernel region [ffffffff801f0000, ffffffff80266000) flags 0x18 name 'kernel_bss'
[00000.000] 00000.00000> VM: reserving kernel region [ffffffff93429000, ffffffff94427000) flags 0x18 name 'kernel_bootalloc'
[00000.000] 00000.00000> VM: freeing region [ffffffff80000000, ffffffff80100000)
[00000.000] 00000.00000> VM: freeing region [ffffffff80266000, ffffffff93429000)
[00000.000] 00000.00000> VM: freeing region [ffffffff94427000, ffffffffc0000000)
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff801002f8 (acpi_tables) at level 0x50001, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff801022f8 (display_memtype) at level 0x50001, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff80100b9c (hpet) at level 0x50002, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff80100e3c (apic) at level 0x50002, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff80103a18 (timer) at level 0x50003, flags 0x1
[00000.000] 00000.00000> Could not find TSC frequency: Calibrating TSC with HPET
[00000.000] 00000.00000> TSC calibrated: 3394448 ticks/ms
[00000.769] 00000.00000> timer features: constant_tsc 1 invariant_tsc 1 tsc_deadline 1
[00000.769] 00000.00000> Using TSC as wallclock
[00000.769] 00000.00000> initializing mp
[00000.769] 00000.00000> initializing threads
[00000.769] 00000.00000> initializing timers
[00000.769] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff80132ec8 (debuglog) at level 0x6ffff, flags 0x1
[00000.769] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff80152a80 (thread_set_priority_experiment) at level 0x6ffff, flags 0x1
[00000.769] 00000.00000> thread set priority experiment is : DISABLED
[00000.769] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff8017cab8 (global_prng_thread_safe) at level 0x6ffff, flags 0x1
[00000.769] 00000.00000> creating bootstrap completion thread
[00000.808] 00000.00000> top of bootstrap2()
[00000.808] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff8017f06c (dpc) at level 0x70000, flags 0x1
[00000.810] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff80191e80 (magenta) at level 0x70000, flags 0x1
[00000.811] 00000.00000> OOM: started thread
[00000.811] 00000.00000> Processor Model Info: type 0 family 0x6 model 0xa stepping 0x7
[00000.811] 00000.00000>        display_family 0x6 display_model 0x2a
[00000.811] 00000.00000> Vendor: Intel
[00000.811] 00000.00000> Microarch: Sandy Bridge
[00000.811] 00000.00000> Features: fpu sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 sse4.1 sse4.2 mmx avx fxsr xsave tsc_adj syscall nx rdtscp
[00000.811] 00000.00000> invar_tsc tsc_deadline hypervisor
[00000.811] 00000.00000> initializing platform
[00000.811] 00000.00000> cpu topology:
[00000.811] 00000.00000>        0: apic id 0x0 package 0 core 0 smt 0 BSP
[00000.811] 00000.00000>        1: apic id 0x1 package 1 core 0 smt 0
[00000.811] 00000.00000>        2: apic id 0x2 package 2 core 0 smt 0
[00000.811] 00000.00000>        3: apic id 0x3 package 3 core 0 smt 0
[00000.811] 00000.00000> Found 4 cpus
[00000.820] 00000.00000> booting apic ids: 0x1 0x2 0x3
[00000.830] 00000.00000> entering scheduler on cpu 1
[00000.830] 00000.00000> entering scheduler on cpu 2
[00000.830] 00000.00000> entering scheduler on cpu 3
[00000.832] 00000.00000> initializing target
[00000.832] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff801032c0 (x86_pcie_init) at level 0x90000, flags 0x1
[00000.832] 00000.00000> calling apps_init()
[00000.832] 00000.00000> INIT: cpu 0, calling hook 0xffffffff801378bc (ktrace) at level 0xaffff, flags 0x1
*
```

GUI is not getting launched please suggest me some solution.

Comment: how did you get the code, what commit are you on

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`frun -m 4096 -g -k -N -u start-dhcp-server.sh`

Let me know if you face any problem.